# <img> next to some text on a line is unaligned?

Tags: html, image

I have an `<img>` next to some text to be outputted on my website:

Here is HTML source/code:

```
1x <img src="1s.png">
```

But when it is outputted into the web browser (IE and FF and I'm assuming Chrome), the image is 'shunted' up 1 or 2 pixels so when you highlight it is higher and not in line with the text.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: What's "shunting"? I get [nothing](http://www.google.hr/search?q=define%3Ashunting) from Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) to align the image vertically. - Duh! `:)`

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/KTY2g/

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
1x <img src="1s.png" align="absmiddle">
```

Comment: The `align` content attribute on IMG elements is obsolete and non-conforming and must not be used. [Source](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features). CSS must be used to achieve its functionality.